# performance of stft / fft in python vs c++

Tags: python, c++, fft

i had expected c++ fft to be faster than the python implementation ?
However the time taken is 2x that of the librosa's implementation.

```
Average Time taken for speedtest.cpp : 0.00240
Average Time taken for speedtest.py  : 0.00133
```

- **Here are the 2d stft functions:**

python version of getting fft `x_stft = librosa.stft()`, [source code here](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/LibROSA.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/_modules/librosa/core/spectrum.html#stft).

my c++ version of getting fft, heres a brief explanation of what goes on within the for loop

- Windowing :
  Multiplying the audio with the window function, and putting them into `fftIn`.
- perform the FFT :
  using the `fftw_plan_dft_1d`, performs fft from `fftIn` to `fftOut`.
- store real and imaginary parts of FFT :
  Since `fftOut` is a complex array, i place them into the `fftReal` & `fftImag`.
- Get Magnitude Spectrum :
  Compute the magnitude from the real and imaginary components.

```cpp
  void computeFullFFT(int numFrames, int nfft, int hop_length, vector<double> &buffer, double windowFunction[], double * Spectrogram){
      // Init
          // initialise audio frame
              vector<double> audioFrame(nfft, 0);
          // initialise the fft time and frequency domain audio frame arrays
              fftw_plan p;          /**< fftw plan */
              fftw_complex* fftIn;  /**< to hold complex fft values for input */
              fftw_complex* fftOut; /**< to hold complex fft values for output */
              vector<double> fftReal(nfft,0);
              vector<double> fftImag(nfft,0);
              int COLS = nfft/2;
              // complex array to hold fft data
              fftIn  = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc (sizeof (fftw_complex) * nfft);
              fftOut = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc (sizeof (fftw_complex) * nfft);
              // FFT plan initialisation
              p = fftw_plan_dft_1d (nfft, fftIn, fftOut, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

      // performFFT & Update Spectrogram
      for (int frameidx=0; frameidx<numFrames; ++frameidx){
              // Windowing
                  for (int i = 0; i < nfft; i++){
                          fftIn[i][0] = buffer[frameidx*hop_length + i] * windowFunction[i];
                          fftIn[i][1] = 0.0;
                  }

              // perform the FFT
                  fftw_execute (p);

              // store real and imaginary parts of FFT
                  for (int i = 0; i < nfft; i++){
                          fftReal[i] = fftOut[i][0];
                          fftImag[i] = fftOut[i][1];
                  }

              // Get Magnitude Spectrum
                  for (int i = 0; i < nfft / 2; i++){
                          *(Spectrogram+frameidx * COLS+i) = (fftReal[i] * fftReal[i]) + (fftImag[i] * fftImag[i]);
                  }
      }
      // destroy fft plan
          fftw_destroy_plan (p);
          fftw_free (fftIn);
          fftw_free (fftOut);
  }
```

- **Here are the main scripts:**

speedtest.cpp

```cpp
  int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
      // Pre-allocate buffer and Spectrogram
          int nfft = 512;
          int hop_length = nfft/2;
          int numFrames = 214;
          vector<double> buffer(40000, 0);
          double Spectrogram[numFrames][nfft/2] = {0};

      // Create Window
          double windowFunction[nfft];
          windowFunction = computeWindow(nfft);

      // Iteration over 100 files starts here
          for(int idx=0; idx<100; ++idx){
              // read audio into buffer here
                  buffer = read_audio(filepath);

              // Compute FFT : Average time taken is 0.003249
                  computeFullFFT(numFrames, nfft, hop_length, buffer, (double*)windowFunction, (double*)Spectrogram);
          }

      return 0 ;
  }
```

speedtest.py

```py
  nfft = 372;
  hop_length = nfft/2;
  numFrames = 214;

  for wav_path in open("TextfileContainWavpaths",'r'):
      x_wav, sr_out = librosa.load(wav_path, sr=8000)

      # Average time taken : 0.00185797069221735
      x_stft = librosa.stft(y=x_wav, n_fft=nfft, win_length=nfft, hop_length=hop_length, center=False, window=np.ones((nfft,)))
```

Comment: When doing such benchmarks, I've seen people doing extremely silly things, including compiling the C++ source with debug & no optimization. Also the implementation in one of the languages has issues. Just by a quick look over your code, I spotted that you pass the vectors by value, not by reference. Is that really necessary? I also believe that librosa uses fft from numpy, which has fft implemented in C: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/numpy/fft so it's not really a benchmark against python.

Comment: @AdrianRoman thanks for your comment, i have made the necessary changes. from 10x slower, it now becomes 2x slower. while it did improve , it is still slower. any idea how can i optimise it ?

Comment: From a quick look, you might want to do the allocations that you do in computeFullFFT, along with computing the fft plan, only once, instead of each call. Also allocating the fftReal and fftImag, then copying data into those seems not really necessary, you can do the computation directly using fftOut.